# compile error User-defined type not defined at "oShell As WshShell"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am currently using MS Access 2016 database. I get this compile error below

> "compile error User-defined type not defined" at the code where it is
> Dim oShell As WshShell

Below is the program. I dont understand where the problem is. Can anyone help me.

```
Sub SetWebControlAsIE9()
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim oShell As WshShell
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim nErr As Long
    Dim bNewStart As Boolean
    
    Set oShell = New WshShell
    
    sKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\msaccess.exe"
    On Error Resume Next
    vKey = oShell.RegRead(sKey)
    nErr = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    If nErr = -2147024894 Then
        oShell.RegWrite sKey, 9999, "REG_DWORD"
        Debug.Print "IE9 Mode set"
        bNewStart = True
    Else
        If vKey <> 9999 Then
            oShell.RegWrite sKey, 9999, "REG_DWORD"
            Debug.Print "IE9 Mode set"
            bNewStart = True
        Else
            Debug.Print "IE9 Mode is already set"
        End If
    End If
    Set oShell = Nothing
    
    If bNewStart Then
        RestartAccess
    End If
    
End Sub
```

```
Sub RestartAccess()
    If MsgBox("Die Datenbank und Access müssen neu gestartet werden," & vbCrLf & _
        "weil die Einstellungen für das WebControl geändert wurden." & vbCrLf & _
        "Jetzt neu starten?", vbQuestion Or vbYesNo, "Bestätigen:") = vbYes Then
        
        Dim sExec As String
        Dim oShell As Object
        
        sExec = Chr$(34) & SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) & "msaccess.exe" & Chr$(34) & _
                " " & Chr$(34) & CurrentDb.Name & Chr$(34)
        oShell.Exec sExec
        Application.Quit acQuitSaveNone
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use late binding instead (not adding the reference) then you can change this

```
Dim oShell As WshShell
```

to this

```
Dim oShell As Object
```

and then change this

```
Set oShell = New WshShell
```

to this

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I think it works but I get the error now on a different part of the program. I just added the Sub RestartAccess part of program to the above my question. Do I have to make the same changes to this part of the script? on "oShell.Exec sExec" line the debugger highlights.

Comment: In your second routine, you have the first part that `Dim`s the object, but you dont have the second line that `Set`s the object. You have to have both.

Comment: I didn't get that exactly, sorry I am a beginner to VBA.

Comment: What didnt you get? Your second routine needs this line too - `Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` - Put it after the `Dim` line.