# Chrome / ChromeDriver version 115 download using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, installation, selenium-chromedriver, driver

This question sort of "piggy-backs" on a previous conversation:
[How Do I Automatically Update the ChromeDriver or EdgeDriver in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67996165/how-do-i-automatically-update-the-chromedriver-or-edgedriver-in-vba)

As of Chrome version 115 ... they have a new directory structure.
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Chrome: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.110/win64/chrome-win64.zip

ChromeDriver: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.110/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

As usual they have no code for VBA.
JSON:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json

The GOOD news is that Chrome and ChromeDriver are now guaranteed to match as they are both updated concurrently.

he BAD news is that you still have to download and install ChromeDriver as a separate task.

Google updates are handled by our IT department, so I'm at a loss to code this to:
A) Check the current version of Chrome. (Can use existing method of obtaining it from the Windows Registry?)
b) Downloading and installing the matching ChromeDriver.

I need someone smarter than me to create the correct VBA code to do this, please.

This is new, and attempts to re-write have been unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an answer to fully cover both of the points you raise ... but hopefully this will get you going in the right direction. I'm assuming you are using a Windows device, BTW.

**For point A 'current version of Chrome':**

You can access the version (actually either the "File version" or the "Product version") with this Function

```
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Try to get a property of a file
' Parameter sFilePath (String): The full path to the file
' Parameter sPropertyName (String): The file property to get details for eg "Size", "Date accessed", "Product version"
'     ... which properties are available depends on the file, the parent folder and the OS
' Parameter outsPropertyValue (String): If the file has such a property, will be updated to hold the property value
' Returns (Boolean): True if the property exists, False otherwise
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function TryGetFileProperty(sFilePath As String, sPropertyName As String, ByRef outsPropertyValue As String) _
        As Boolean
    ' for early binding, add a reference to 'Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation' and use the commented-out types
    Dim oShellApp As Object ' Shell32.Shell
    Dim oShellFolder As Object ' Shell32.Folder
    Dim oShellFolderItem As Object ' Shell32.FolderItem
    
    Dim lFileNameStart As Long
    lFileNameStart = InStrRev(sFilePath, "\")
    
    Set oShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oShellFolder = oShellApp.Namespace(Left$(sFilePath, lFileNameStart))
    Set oShellFolderItem = oShellFolder.Items.Item(Mid$(sFilePath, lFileNameStart + 1))
    
    ' file properties can only be accessed by index number, however, the index number (and therefore the maximum index
    ' number - here 350) can vary (by file / folder / Windows version?) so we iterate over all properties to find the
    ' one with a name that matches the supplied property name ... if we find the property with the supplied name, then
    ' return its value
    Dim i As Long
    For i = -1 To 350
        If StrComp(oShellFolder.GetDetailsOf(oShellFolder.Items, i), sPropertyName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            outsPropertyValue = oShellFolder.GetDetailsOf(oShellFolderItem, i)
            TryGetFileProperty = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

... the Function is documented to explain what it does and how it does it so I won't go into it further other than to provide this usage example:

```
Sub ExampleUsage()
    Const sFILE_PATH As String = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    Const sPROPERTY_NAME As String = "Product version"
    Dim sPropertyValue As String
    If TryGetFileProperty(sFILE_PATH, sPROPERTY_NAME, sPropertyValue) Then
        Debug.Print sPROPERTY_NAME & " is " & sPropertyValue
    Else
        Debug.Print "Could not get the " & sPROPERTY_NAME
    End If
End Sub
```

... on my device, this prints "Product version is 115.0.5790.110" to the Immediate window.

BTW, if you want to see all of the properties available for a particular file then use this:

```
Sub LogAllFileProperties(sFilePath As String, Optional bOnlyWithValidValue As Boolean = True)
    ' for early binding, add a reference to 'Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation' and use the commented-out types
    Dim oShellApp As Object ' Shell32.Shell
    Dim oShellFolder As Object ' Shell32.Folder
    Dim oShellFolderItem As Object ' Shell32.FolderItem
    
    Dim lFileNameStart As Long
    lFileNameStart = InStrRev(sFilePath, "\")
    
    Set oShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oShellFolder = oShellApp.Namespace(Left$(sFilePath, lFileNameStart))
    Set oShellFolderItem = oShellFolder.Items.Item(Mid$(sFilePath, lFileNameStart + 1))

    Dim i As Long, sDetailName As String, sDetailValue As String
    For i = -1 To 350
        sDetailName = oShellFolderItem.Parent.GetDetailsOf(oShellFolder.Items, i)
        sDetailValue = oShellFolderItem.Parent.GetDetailsOf(oShellFolderItem, i)
        If Len(sDetailValue) > 0 Or (Not bOnlyWithValidValue And Len(sDetailName) > 0) Then
            Debug.Print Format(i, "000") & ": '" & sDetailName & "' = '" & sDetailValue & "'"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

... just pass it the full path to the file.

**For point B 'downloading and installing ChromeDriver':**

I can only point you in the direction of other SO answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer) for downloading.

Assuming you are doing this in order to use SeleniumBasic, I believe (happy to be corrected!) that ChromeDriver doesn't actually need to be 'installed' as such, only that the downloaded file needs to be unzipped (again there are a number of SO answers on unzipping for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717193/unzip-folder-with-files-to-the-chosen-location)) and then copied into the same folder as the SeleniumBasic type library file.

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.twbts.com/thread-23792-6-1.html
52#

Since some people are unaware of the need to install the main plugin, the plugin installation process has also been added.
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases
SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0.exe
After the first installation is complete, you must go to Start > Run Selenium's "start chrome".
Wait for the error to pop up and confirm. This will automatically install the .net Framework. Once the installation is complete, reboot the system.
After restarting, run this program to update the version.

```
Sub updateSelenium()
' Since selenium might be installed in one of two folders under Windows, we need to find the correct folder first (Mac is not considered currently)
path1 = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\Chromedriver.exe"
path2 = "C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver.exe"
If Dir(path1) <> "" Then TempDrvFile = path1
If Dir(path2) <> "" Then TempDrvFile = path2
foler = Left(TempDrvFile, InStrRev(TempDrvFile, "\")) 'Get the folder path and the path to chromedriver.exe
' If Selenium 2.0.9.0 is not installed, the user will be directed to the GitHub site to download and install it manually
If foler = "" Then
    msg = "(Please screenshot or capture this screen)" & vbCrLf
    msg = msg & "Cannot find the Selenium plugin folder. Please visit the website: " & vbCrLf & "https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases"
    msg = msg & vbCrLf & "Download and install SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0.exe" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to visit now?"
    msg = msg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please note the following steps:" & vbCrLf & "After the first installation, go to Start > Run Selenium's 'start chrome'" & vbCrLf
    msg = msg & "Wait for the error message and confirm. It will auto-install .net framework. Restart your computer after installation." & vbCrLf & "Run this program again to update the version."
    x = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Plugin not installed")
    If x = 6 Then
    edgePath1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
    edgePath2 = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
    If Dir(edgePath1) <> "" Then edgePath = edgePath1
    If Dir(edgePath2) <> "" Then edgePath = edgePath2
    edgePath = """" & edgePath & """" & " https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases"
    Call Shell(edgePath, vbNormalFocus)
    End If
Exit Sub
End If

' Get the current chromedriver version's first two digits, e.g., 117.0
Set oShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
errcode = oShell.Exec(TempDrvFile & " --version").StdOut.ReadAll
verarr = Split(errcode, " ")
chrdrv = verarr(1)
dotsarr2 = Split(chrdrv, ".")

' Obtain the current version of the Chrome browser, e.g., 117.0
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
chrversion = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon\version")
dotsarr = Split(chrversion, ".")
leftchrver = dotsarr(0) & dotsarr(1)

' Compare chromedriver and Chrome browser version numbers. If they are the same, exit (no update); otherwise, visit the official site to check the latest browser version and continue to download and replace
leftchrdrv = dotsarr2(0) & dotsarr2(1)
If leftchrver = leftchrdrv Then Exit Sub

' Access the official API to obtain version info and extract it. This info is in JSON format. The available chromedriver version for the current browser is also extracted
' This method of extracting from JSON is custom-made. It does not conform to standard JSON. We are unsure if the format will change in the future, and we don't want to include additional objects
Url = "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/latest-versions-per-milestone.json"
Call objHTTP.Open("GET", Url, False)
Call objHTTP.Send("")
version_number = objHTTP.responseText
v0 = Split(version_number, ",""milestones"":{")
v1 = Split(v0(1), "},")
For i = 0 To UBound(v1)
v1(i) = Replace(v1(i), """", "")
v1(i) = Replace(v1(i), ":{milestone:", ",")
v1(i) = Replace(v1(i), ",version:", ",")
v1(i) = Replace(v1(i), ",revision:", ",")
v1(i) = Replace(v1(i), "}}}", ",")
Next
ReDim v2(UBound(v1))
For i = 0 To UBound(v1): v2(i) = Split(v1(i), ","): Next
For i = 0 To UBound(v2)
If v2(i)(0) = dotsarr(0) Then: version_number = v2(i)(2): Exit For
Next

' Generate the download link (Note: we also need to consider the OS bit version, which might change the cmd part below). It is uncertain if the download URL will change in the future
'download_url = "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/" & version_number & "/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip"
'download_url = "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/" & version_number & "/mac-x64/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip"
'download_url = "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/" & version_number & "/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip"
download_url = "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/" & version_number & "/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip"
    Call objHTTP.Open("GET", download_url, False)
    Call objHTTP.Send("")

' Use ADODB.Stream to receive the file
Set fileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With fileStream
    .Open
    .Type = 1 ' Binary type
    .Write objHTTP.responseBody
    .Position = 0
    .SaveToFile foler & "chromedriver.zip", 2 ' Download the file to the Selenium folder. '2 means overwrite
    .Close
End With

' Use shell+cmd to delete old files. The kill method is blocked by Microsoft
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 cmdCommand = "cmd /c del " & foler & "chromedriver.exe"    
 Call Shell(cmdCommand, vbHide)                         
 cmdCommand = "cmd /c del " & foler & "LICENSE.chromedriver"
 Call Shell(cmdCommand, vbHide)                            
            If Dir(foler & "chromedriver.exe") <> "" Then
            cmdCommand = "cmd /c taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe && cmd /c del " & foler & "chromedriver.exe"  
            Call Shell(cmdCommand, vbHide)
            End If
            If Dir(foler & "LICENSE.chromedriver") <> "" Then
            cmdCommand = "cmd /c taskkill /F /IM LICENSE.chromedriver && cmd /c del " & foler & "LICENSE.chromedriver"  
            Call Shell(cmdCommand, vbHide)
            End If

' Unzip the new chromedriver.exe to the directory. 16 is the force- replace option. Note that the file name inside the zip might vary depending on the system bit version
oApp.Namespace(foler).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(foler & "chromedriver.zip\chromedriver-win64").items, 16

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to fully automatic download the latest version and install in the desired folders.
You have to adjust the paths to your needs.

```
Sub DownloadChromeDriver()
    Dim url As String
    Dim http As Object, oStream As Object
    Dim localPath As String

    url = "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.send

    If http.Status = 200 Then
        Dim latestVersion As String
        latestVersion = http.responseText

        url = "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/" & latestVersion & "/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip"

        localPath = "C:\Users\Public\chromedriver_win32.zip" ' Replace with your desired path

        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        http.Open "GET", url, False
        http.send

        If http.Status = 200 Then
            Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            oStream.Open
            oStream.Type = 1
            oStream.Write http.responseBody
            oStream.SaveToFile localPath, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
            oStream.Close
            'MsgBox "ChromeDriver downloaded successfully."
            'now unzip
            If Len(Dir$("C:\Users\Toebak\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver.exe")) > 0 Then
                ' File Exists, Delete it
                Kill "C:\Users\Toebak\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver.exe"
                Kill "C:\Users\Toebak\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver-win32\LICENSE.chromedriver"
            End If
            
            Call UnzipAFile("C:\Users\Public\chromedriver_win32.zip", "C:\Users\Toebak\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic")
                 Else
            'MsgBox "Failed to download ChromeDriver."
        End If
    Else
        'MsgBox "Failed to get the latest version."
    End If
End Sub`

Sub UnzipAFile(zippedFileFullName As Variant, unzipToPath As Variant)
    Dim ShellApp As Object
    'Copy the files & folders from the zip into a folder
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ShellApp.Namespace(unzipToPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).Items
    FileCopy "C:\Users\Toebak\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver.exe", "C:\Users\Toebak\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver.exe"
    FileCopy "C:\Users\Toebak\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver-win32\LICENSE.chromedriver", "C:\Users\Toebak\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\LICENSE.chromedriver"
End Sub
```